# Populating referenced collections in MongoDB from JSON files using Node.js and Mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am Populating referenced collections in MongoDB from JSON files using Node.js and Mongoose

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
username: String,
sites : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Site' }], 
});

var SiteSchema = new Schema({
user : { type: String, ref: 'User' },
siteTitle: String, 
pages : [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: prefix + 'Page' }],
});

var PageSchema = new Schema({
site: { type: String, ref: 'Site' },
title: String,
});

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
var user = new User(req.body);
user.save(function(err) { // create user 
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        var site = new Site({user: user.username, siteTitle: user.username});
        site.save(function(err) { // create website
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                user.sites.push(site); // push site'id in sites field in user
                user.save(); // save user after site'id has been push

                for (var i=0; i<basePages.length; i++) { // create pages from base.json file
                    var page = new Page(basePages[i]);
                    page.save(function(err) { // create page
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        } else {
                            site.pages.push(page);
                            site.save();
                        }
                    });
                   res.json(user);
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
};
```

Pages are well created from the JSON file and pages field in Site document are populated but I have only one ID. I mean my JSON file has 2 pages so I get

pages: "_id123456", "_id123456" from

```
site.pages.push(page);
site.save();
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, what are you trying to achieve and what's failing?

Comment: I have add the Schemas to make the question more clear. What I am trying is to populate page ids created from the Json file into "pages" inside SiteSchema. It seems the loops with site.pages.push(page); site.save(); is returning the same page ids for each i

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I found myself :) just add page as argument in page.save function;

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
var user = new User(req.body);
user.save(function(err) { // create user 
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    } else {
        var site = new Site({user: user.username, siteTitle: user.username});
        site.save(function(err) { // create website
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            } else {
                user.sites.push(site); // push site'id in sites field in user
                user.save(); // save user after site'id has been push
                for (var i=0; i<basePages.length; i++) { // create pages from base.json file
                    var page = new Page(basePages[i]);
                    page.save(function(err, **page**) { // create page
                        if (err) {
                            return next(err);
                        } else {
                            site.pages.push(**page**);
                            site.save();
                        };
                    });
                };
                res.json(user);
            };
        });
    };
});
};
```